# Display website as wallpaper?

Tags: release-hera, wallpaper

Is it possible in elementary OS 5.1 Hera to display a website as wallpaper? I'd love to render https://wall.marco.betschart.name/ as my dynamically changing wallpaper, but I'm not able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done by Komorebi, it allows you to set a webpage or a video as your wallpaper.

1. Download the .deb file from :
   https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi/releases
2. install it using gdebi or the dpkg command from terminal
3. search for wallpaper creator 
   there you can easily set the webpage as your wallpaper.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/animated-wallpaper-background-ubuntu-18-04/